# Detached Entity and Managed Entity

Tags: java, database, jpa, ejb, entity

What a "detached entity" means?
How is it possible to convert a managed entity to a detached entity during a transaction?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A detached entity is an entity whose state must not be reflected by the JPA provider.

In other words, if you change its state (i.e. through setters methods) these changes will not be saved to the underlying database, as the JPA provider doesn't have to "observe" such entities.

If entity E1 is a managed entity you can make it detached invoking (very reasonable named) method [`EntityManager#detach(E1)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach%28java.lang.Object%29). You can also use [`EntityManager#clear()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#clear%28%29) which will clear whole PersistenceContext and effectively making all managed entities detached.

Comment: note that not all versions of JPA implementations offer detach

Answer (score 10):

> actually, what is meant by a detached entity?

Detached entity objects are objects in a special state in which they are not managed by any `EntityManager` but still represent objects in the database. Read more [source](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/detach)

> and How it is possible convert a managed entity to a detached entity during a transaction?

[Read here](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/managed)

Answer (score 9):

[Here](http://java.boot.by/scbcd5-guide/ch06.html) you can read about JPA entity lifecycle.

Entity can be detached after serializing or closing of Persistence Context, for example.