# Disable auto-update from JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Some times when i wanna just change a value of attribute (without UPDATE) the JPA/Hibernate launch the "update" (against my desire), i just know that because i did i "SELECT" in database in exact time, because any SQL apper in my console.

Look my code:

```
 bean.setDescription('TEST'); 
 //do a lot of code here..
```

My problem is: After execute "bean.setDescription()" the value in database changes (unexpectedly), but i don't wanna that, because in the END of this block of code i will change the value to orign.

Answer (score 0):

JPA uses managed entities. That means that whatever changes you make to a managed entity within a session are persisted when that session is closed or flushed.

If you don't want that behavior, you need to manually detach the entity. [See here on how to do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441450/detached-entity-and-managed-entity)